# Coloring the "empty space" in an inline-block layout

Tags: html, css

I have a simple two column `inline-block`-based layout that consists of a series of chunks that look like:

```css
.doc {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5em;
  width: 30%;
}
.code {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">

  <div class="doc">
    Documentation goes here.
  </div>

  <div class="code">
    <pre><code>
      int main () {
        printf("The code goes here.\n");
      }
      </code></pre>
  </div>

</div>
```

I would like the right "column" to have a `background-color`, so I
naively tried this:

```css
.code {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
```

But that presented several problems:

1. The `background-color` is only applied to the length of the lines in
   the `<pre>` block, leaving a ragged right edge.

   I can solve this particular issue if I specify an absolute `width` on the `class="code"` column, like this:

```css
.code {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  width: 5in;
}
```

but I don't want an absolute `width` there.  I tried `width: 100%`
  (by which I meant "the `width` of the containing element"), but that
  had no effect.

1. The `background-color` is *not* applied to "empty space" that occurs
   when the left `<div>` (`class="doc"`) is longer than the right
   `<div>`.

   I'm not sure how to resolve this one.

How do I get the "empty space" in both of these examples to have the
correct `background-color`?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/pc7jwywL/2/) is a jsfiddle.

Comment: best bet is to use flexbox, but are you limited to using inline-blocks?

Comment: Hello, -1 voter who stopped by today.  Any chance you would care to leave a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## option #1 (for modern browsers)

- use `flexbox`

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  margin:10px 0
}
.doc {
  margin-right: 5em;
  width: 30%;
}
.code {
  background-color: red;
  flex:1
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">

  <div class="doc">
    <p>
      Documentation goes here.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut lobortis rutrum leo, interdum rutrum dui consectetur eget. Sed sed odio pellentesque, efficitur enim a, ornare odio. Pellentesque semper metus vel ligula tristique, eu suscipit odio porta. Pellentesque
      sagittis nunc sapien, non finibus elit congue ullamcorper. Duis et vulputate sem. Suspendisse dictum egestas sapien, vitae bibendum felis aliquet et. In a augue facilisis, luctus sem ut, auctor nulla. Nullam eget libero in mauris blandit pretium.
      Sed sed porta nunc. Etiam faucibus sed nisl eu suscipit. Phasellus scelerisque in purus in convallis. Donec sed sem ipsum. Nulla ultricies tempus quam, a faucibus quam tincidunt ac. Etiam et purus ultricies, pretium justo vehicula, venenatis risus.
      Vivamus purus dui, auctor id posuere in, dapibus convallis lorem.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="code">
    <pre><code>
  int main () {
    printf("The code goes here.\n");
  }
  
  // here is
  // some other code
  </code></pre>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="outer">

  <div class="doc">
    Documentation goes here.
  </div>

  <div class="code">
    <pre><code>
  int main () {
    printf("The code goes here.\n");
  }
  </code></pre>
  </div>

</div>
```

## option #2 (for old browsers)

- use `table/table-cell`

```css
.outer {
  display: table;
  margin:10px 0
}
.doc {
  padding-right: 5em;
  width: 30%;
  display: table-cell
}
.code {
  background-color: red;
  display: table-cell
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">

  <div class="doc">
    <p>
      Documentation goes here.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut lobortis rutrum leo, interdum rutrum dui consectetur eget. Sed sed odio pellentesque, efficitur enim a, ornare odio. Pellentesque semper metus vel ligula tristique, eu suscipit odio porta. Pellentesque
      sagittis nunc sapien, non finibus elit congue ullamcorper. Duis et vulputate sem. Suspendisse dictum egestas sapien, vitae bibendum felis aliquet et. In a augue facilisis, luctus sem ut, auctor nulla. Nullam eget libero in mauris blandit pretium.
      Sed sed porta nunc. Etiam faucibus sed nisl eu suscipit. Phasellus scelerisque in purus in convallis. Donec sed sem ipsum. Nulla ultricies tempus quam, a faucibus quam tincidunt ac. Etiam et purus ultricies, pretium justo vehicula, venenatis risus.
      Vivamus purus dui, auctor id posuere in, dapibus convallis lorem.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="code">
    <pre><code>
  int main () {
    printf("The code goes here.\n");
  }
  
  // here is
  // some other code
  </code></pre>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="outer">

  <div class="doc">
    Documentation goes here.
  </div>

  <div class="code">
    <pre><code>
  int main () {
    printf("The code goes here.\n");
  }
  </code></pre>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: TIL about `flexbox`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On reliable way to work cross browser (on older versions of IE) is to use Javascript. Create a function that runs on document ready, and then whenever the screen width is resized. The function would need to reset the height of both columns, measure the height of both, and then set the height to which ever column is tallest.

```
adjustColumnHeight();

$(window).resize(function(){
    adjustColumnHeight()
});

var adjustColumnHeight = function() {

    // Set height of both columns to auto

    // Find height of each column

    // Set both columns to the height of the tallest column
};
```

It might be a good idea to debounce the resize() by putting adjustColumnHeight() inside a setTimeout so it doesn't execute so often.